# Installing Kubuntu 15.10 x64: An error occurred while restoring previously-installed applications

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu

I try to install Kubuntu 15.10 x64 from a DVD. At the last step of the installation, I get the error message:

> An error occurred while restoring previously-installed applications. The
>   installation will continue, but you may have to manually reinstall some applications after the computer reboots."

What could cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue stemmed from the fact that when choosing the partition on which to install Kubuntu, I was deleting then creating a new one. I instead selected the partition, clicked on "changed", marked as to be formatted and to be mounted as `\`: this time, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. This question is the top Google hit for "An error occurred while restoring previously-installed applications", so I'll confirm your finding that the error is invoked by installing to a partition that you'd formatted *prior* to the installation rather than during the installation. It's still happening with (K)ubuntu 19.04. I've raised a new bug report against the installer (Ubiquity), because although bug reports on this date back to 2012, the previous reports didn't explicitly state the cause:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1825355