# 12.04 LTS -> 14.04 LTS: An error occurred while restoring previously-installed applications

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade, virtualbox

I'm attempting to upgrade an existing installation of Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS to 14.04.4 LTS in a 5.0.10 VirtualBox VM. After several hours of attempting to get `do-release-upgrade` to find any new releases at all, I gave up and upgraded via ISO. However, at the end of the upgrade, the following error occurs:

`An error occurred while restoring previously-installed applications. The installation will continue, but you may have to manually reinstall some applications after the computer reboots.`

There seems to be very little information about this problem on the web - there's [this AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698727/installing-kubuntu-15-10-x64-an-error-occurred-while-restoring-previously-insta) but the solution isn't applicable here as far as I can tell.

The error message itself doesn't provide any useful information regarding how to resolve the problem. I've restored the previous snapshot at this point so I'm ready to try the install again, but I don't know how to proceed re fixing the issue. If anyone has any pointers as to where I could get more information about the problem, or ideally, a fix, that'd be great.